# Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() causing "Error creating bean with name "

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot, concurrency

I have a ThreadPoolTaskExecutor defined as:

```
@Configuration
public class MyTaskExecutor 
    {    /**     * creates PrepTaskSchedulerConfig bean at startup     * @return ThreadPoolTaskScheduler bean     */    
        @Bean 
        public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor myExecutor(){        
            ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();        
            threadPoolTaskExecutor.setThreadNamePrefix("MyExecutor");        
      
            threadPoolTaskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(5);        
            threadPoolTaskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());        
            return threadPoolTaskExecutor;    
        }
    }
```

And this bean will be get from the application context as:

```
ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor = m_applicationContext.getBean(ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.class);
```

When build it on my local machine, everything is fine. But after submitted the code to the gitlab, and run the build there, it has build error:

> Error creating bean with name Invocation of init method failed
> exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

But if I remove `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()` and change that line to:

```
threadPoolTaskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(10);
```

Also, if I remove the `@Configuration`annotation (remain setMaxPoolSize unchanged), the error is also gone.

Everything passes. Want to know why
Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() causing "Error creating bean with name " ?

Comment: Have you read the stacktrace? It probably tells you that the `maxPoolSize` needs to be larger then the `corePoolSize`.

Comment: Thanks, but No such words in the stack trace

Comment: Add the stacktrace. The full one not just a snippet.

Comment: Although the error message probably doesn't contain that information (`ThreadPoolExecutor#setMaximumPoolSize` throws an empty IllegalArgumentException in that case), it should provide the info that the Exception originates from the call to `ThreadPoolExecutor#setMaximumPoolSize`, not `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()`.

Comment: Thanks, but no string containing "Max" in the stacktrack. Moreover, if I remove @Configure annotation, the error is also gone

Comment: Would suggest you to share complete stacktrace in question.

Comment: Wait, what? This error occurs when you “submit the code to the gitlab”?